# Hibernate post load event listener - not all data present

Tags: java, hibernate

Hibernate version 4.3.10-final

I have an entity called account that declares child transaction table as follows

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "account", orphanRemoval = true)
@OrderBy("transactionDate desc")
private Set<Transaction> transactionList;
```

Transaction list is lazily loaded hibernate loads it when needed. I do perform some actions in the post load event which works fine when I load account object, but when hibernate loads transaction list (when code accesses transaction list, which does not happen every time), I get another post load event for account. In this case post load data is not correctly set for account. For example in following code, my logs do show the key, but deep inside where hibernate loads account again when getTransactionList is called, same account object can not access key. getUser does not return null, but its not loaded either - all this happenning on already loaded object.

```
    final String key = account.getUser().getKey(); 
    if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
        log.info("got key {}", key);
    }
    for (final Transaction transaction : account.getTransactionList())
  { 
     // do something
  }
```

How do I ensure post load will work correctly?

Comment: _" getUser does not return null, but its not loaded either"_ What does getUser return then? :)

Comment: It looks like its empty. Except ID field, all other fields (even not nullable fields) are null. It looks like in the stage of construction or half baked